# How to avoid commit status

Tags: git

I am enforcing a shell script which executes on post-commit. In that `git diff` is used to compare a specific file on every commit. While doing so the output of `git diff` is not shown in color and there is no scroll wait. I found that it can be due to the status which displays `"1 file changed, 5 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)"` after the commit command. Please help how to avoid it?